# hortonworks sandbox hive metastore not works

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-sandbox

Version: Horton works Sandbox 2.6.5_1 on Virtual box
After install could not find mysql root password so reset mysql root password. Before password reset hive was working, now hive metastore not starting.

Access denied for user 'root'@'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com' (using password: YES)
...
Writing File['/usr/hdp/current/hive-metastore/conf/conf.server/hive-site.jceks'] because contents don't match.

I changed mysql root password to 'hive','bigdata','hadoop' still i could not start hive metastore.

Answer (score 3):

- First time login password for hortonworks HDP is 'hortonworks1'
- It can be change using below steps:-

Step 1:

```
systemctl stop mysqld
```

Step 2:-

```
systemctl set-environment MYSQLD_OPTS="--skip-grant-tables"
```

Step 3:-

```
systemctl start mysqld
```

Step4:-

```
mysql -u root
```

Step 5:-

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Step 6:-

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'devesh';
```

Step 7:-

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
quit;
systemctl stop mysqld
```

Step 8 (Final Step):- Unset the mySQL envitroment option so it starts normally next time

```
systemctl unset-environment MYSQLD_OPTS
systemctl start mysqld
```

Now you can login to mysql using password 'devesh'

Answer (score 1):

Default mysql root password is 'hortonworks1'. After changing to this default password, hive metastore works fine.

But still don't know if we change mysql root password where to change the connection password.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing one thing:

1. Log in to the machine as root
2. Type `mysql` only; if it says `Access Denied(using password:YES)`; Check if the mysql service is running or not
3. How to check; `systemctl status mysqld` OR if you have mariaDB installed then; `systemctl status mariadb`
4. If not active, start mysql and try logging in again.
5. If you fail to login then run the command; `mysqladmin -u root password <your_password>`
6. Login with the root to mysql now and then type the command; `select host,user,password from mysql.user`
7. Check if there is a password set for hive user; if not then follow the hortonworks doc to install hive with mysql.

P.S: Don't forget to use ; after every mysql command.

Comment: Already I tried below items
1. stop/start mysqld after changing new password for 'root'
2. I reset 'hive' user password to 'hive'
3. verified /etc/hive/conf/conf.server/hive-site.xml - 'hive_metastore_user_passwd' is 'hive'
4. I can login into mysql with 'root' and 'hive' user no issues
5. Hive metastore db / database connection verification
https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/155678/hive-metastore-db-connection-verification-from-com.html

Comment: Please attach the log file with the error you're facing. I'll give you the resolution
And try logging in as hive user. From root `su - hive` then access hive metastore

Comment: Hive Metastore not works only after i changed mysql root password. When we change mysql root password I assume in sandbox password is stored for connection. where it is stored, if we change the file we may be ok?

Below is from log file
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to get schema version.
Underlying cause: java.sql.SQLException : Access denied for user 'root'@'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com' (using password: YES)
SQL Error code: 1045

Comment: full log file https://github.com/w3help/code/blob/master/hive_metastore_log

Comment: I see 'Ranger Admin Start' also gives same error msg 

28000 java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com' (using password: YES) ErrorCode: 1045
2018-08-30 17:13:22,761  [E] Can't establish db connection.